# How to Dynamically bin data in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, binning

Is there a way I can dynamically bin the data according to the input.

Here I am trying bin data for .01 increase in Lng . Range of data is 113.88 to 114.3.
Currently I am manually splitting the bins. Is there a more efficient way.

**Current Code**

```
bin_Lng = [113.88,113.89,113.9,113.91,113.92,113.93,113.94,113.95,113.96,113.97,113.98,113.99,114,114.01,114.02,
114.03,114.04,114.05,114.06,114.07,114.08,114.09,114.1,114.11,114.12,114.13,114.14,114.15,114.16,114.17,114.18,114.19,114.2,114.21,114.22,114.23,114.24,
114.25,114.26,114.27,114.28,114.29,114.3]
group_name_lng =['Lng Zone1',
'Lng Zone2','Lng Zone3','Lng Zone4','Lng Zone5','Lng Zone6','Lng Zone7','Lng Zone8','Lng Zone9','Lng Zone10','Lng Zone11',
'Lng Zone12','Lng Zone13','Lng Zone14','Lng Zone15','Lng Zone16','Lng Zone17','Lng Zone18','Lng Zone19','Lng Zone20','Lng Zone21',
'Lng Zone22','Lng Zone23','Lng Zone24','Lng Zone25','Lng Zone26','Lng Zone27','Lng Zone28','Lng Zone29','Lng Zone30',
'Lng Zone31','Lng Zone32','Lng Zone33','Lng Zone34','Lng Zone35','Lng Zone36','Lng Zone37','Lng Zone38','Lng Zone39','Lng Zone40','Lng Zone41',
'Lng Zone42']
data['Lng_Zone'] = pd.cut(data['Lng'], bin_Lng, labels=group_name_lng)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you know the range just use `np.arange` i.e

```
bin_Lng = pd.np.arange(113.88, 114.3,0.01)
group_name_lng = ['Lng Zone{}'.format(i) for i in range(1,len(bin_Lng))]
```

Comment: I am getting the below error when I use your code `ValueError: Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges`

Comment: The error is not occurring when I use original code .

Comment: It was the enumerate, I for a second forgot it was for binning. The above one will work.

Comment: ,its working now. But I guess this takes more time to excute than the orginal code.

Comment: Rahul rajan, this happens at the runtime, constant is always faster than dynamic code. You cant expect the same speed. Nobody can help you with that. If you want speed I suggest you to keep your original code.

Comment: If  range is not known. What would be the approach.

Comment: I think min and max might help `(data['Lng'].min(),data['Lng'].max(),0.1)`, cant be sure though. Depends on type of binning you want.

Comment: @Dark - Nice solution ;)